# Scaling points of line - konvajs

Tags: konvajs

I'm looking to have a transform on a KonvaJS line. I have all of it working and it scales the object, however I'd like it to adjust the points of the line instead of setting the scale property when I grab a resize handle. Would also consider doing this in a path as well.

So the goal is that my objects scaleX and scaleY is always 1 and it's just the points that are scaling out.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to apply the scale to `points` property:

```
shape.on('transformend', () => {
  const oldPoints = shape.points();
  const newPoints = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< oldPoints.length / 2; i++) {
    const point = {
      x: oldPoints[i * 2] * shape.scaleX(),
      y: oldPoints[i * 2 + 1] * shape.scaleY(),
    }
    newPoints.push(point.x, point.y);
  }
  shape.points(newPoints);
  shape.scaleX(1);
  shape.scaleY(1);
  layer.draw();
})
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/vuhakuvoxa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That's not completely true: let's say you increase the size of the shape dragging it from the lower right corner. I expect that the first point of your example (the one on the top-left edge, x: 50, y:50) will not change, and that's not true.
The reality is that, in this way, the points representing the whole shape will shift a little to the bottom right of the stage.

Comment: I improved you example using `shape.getAbsoluteTransform().point({})` and resetting x and y position to 0. In this example, `newPoints` is the exact representation of the points of the resized shape: https://jsbin.com/gojiwuwaqe/edit?html,js,output